# Error making Hotkey

Tags: shortcut

So I'm trying to adjust a simple hotkey and it's giving me a lot of trouble. I want to make it so that Pan is done by holding Spacebar and using the middle click, similar to how it works in photoshop. It's just easier for me that way.
But I realized that Spacebar is "play animation" so I changed that to something else.
I found the Pan option I wanted to change, and made sure it now says:

[image]

However, every time I press spacebar now, I get this error:

[image]

Does anyone know what's causing this, or if it's even possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Thanks,
~Matt M.

Comment: I can in Blender 3 alpha switch to this key configuration without any error at the default Blender keymap. But i cannot move the view then. Even after turning off all other spacebar hotkeys. Which keymap do you use here? And which Blender version? In case you can repeat this error then you might consider to file a bug report.

Comment: Hi there,

I'm using Blender 2.80 
I'm sorry, but I don't actually know what you mean by keymap. If no one else has an answer after a few days, I'll make a bug report.

Comment: Tested and works also in Blender 2.80. I would suggest to update to a newer Blender version. 2.80 is now over 2 years old. And bug reports will just be valid for the actual version, which is currently 2.93.

Comment: And when you don't know what a keymap is. then i guess that you still use the default keymap. You can use other keymaps in Blender too. It comes for example with a keymap called Industry Compatible. You can find it at the top of the keymap settings. Up left, the drop down box where you can read Blender.

Comment: Thanks Tiles, I upgraded to the most recent version and my shortcut seems to be working now. I didn't realize I hadn't updated in some time.